# Select all the <tr> tags less than the index of the focused <tr> tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to access the `<tr>` tags of the focused `<tr>` tag, but it is displaying all of them. Can anyone solve this?

Below is my HTML and javascript code:

```
<table>
   <tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
   <tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Below is the script i have written:

```
 $('TABLE TR TD').find('input').focus(function()
 {
   var ParID=$(this).parents('TR').index();
   $(this).parents('TR').siblings('TR').prevAll("TR").find('input').each(function()
     {
       alert($(this).parents('TR').index()) 
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('table input').focus(function() {
   var $previousRows = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr');
});
```

Your problem is this part: `.siblings('TR').prevAll("TR")`.

As  `.siblings('TR')` returns **all row** (also the last one), `.prevAll("TR")` will return all rows too. Just removing `.siblings('TR')` would probably work fine too.

Note that [`.closest()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is better suited in the situation.